# Maximum value for unsigned int

Tags: c++, int

Here's what I want:

```
unsigned int max_unsigned_int_size;
max_unsigned_int_size = ???;
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Your variable name does not match your title. Do you want the maximum *value* an unsigned int can *represent*, or the maximum *size* an unsigned value can *be*?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### [C](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)

```
#include <limits.h>
unsigned int max_unsigned_int_size = UINT_MAX;
```

#### [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/)

```
#include <limits>
unsigned int max_unsigned_int_size = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

Comment: Or both: `= -1;`.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: Yes. There are plenty of resources on SO discussing this. You can always assign -1 to any unsigned integer type and get the maximum value, guaranteed.

Answer (score 18):

```
unsigned int max_unsigned_int_size = -1;
```

is guaranteed to do the right thing. Arithmetic with unsigned types is always modulo.

But in the concrete case you always should use `UINT_MAX`

Comment: You should use a cast to avoid warnings (at least in Visual Studio): `unsigned int max_unsigned_int_size = (unsigned int) -1;`

Comment: No, in C you should never use casts, they tend to claim that you know what you are doing, even if you aren't. If you have a compiler that complains about signed to unsigned conversion, search for the option that turns this feature off, or if that is not possible, get yourself a standard compliant one.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for

```
#include <limits>
std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```

If you wanted the size, `sizeof` would do, multiply by CHAR_BITS to get the bits.

Alternattively, there is

```
std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need [`std::numeric_limits::max()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)

```
#include <limits>

...

max_insigned_int_size = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max():
```

Answer (score 2):

- For C the value is given by `UINT_MAX` in [`limits.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).
- For C++ you can alternatively use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` from [`limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/).

Comment: For C++ the value of UINT_MAX is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <limits>

max_unsigned_int_size = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();
```